# dbgrid without client dataset

Tags: delphi-2010, dbexpress, delphi

I have a form with a dbgrid and an sqlquery component. I am trying to fill the dbgrid with the sqlquery.  When I do I get the message, "Operation not allowed on Unidirectional dataset."  I do NOT want to use a client data set, as I do not want a 'local' copy of the data, I would like to read and display the data directly. How can this be done?

Answer (score 10):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLQuery) clearly states (emphasis added):

> TSQLQuery is a **unidirectional dataset**. Unlike other datasets, **unidirectional datasets do not buffer multiple records in memory. Because of this, you can only navigate using the First and Next methods**. There is no built-in editing support: you can only edit the data in an SQL query by explicitly creating an SQL UPDATE command or by connecting the dataset to a client dataset using a provider.

Because there's no buffering of multiple records, you can't move in any direction except forward, which means that the `DBGrid` could not display multiple rows or support scrolling.

(In fact, all of the `DBExpress` components are unidirectional, according to the documentation on [Types of DBExpress DataSets](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Types_of_dbExpress_Datasets).)

You'll have to either use a `TClientDataSet` or change from using `DBExpress` to some other method of accessing the data such as `ADO` instead, or display the data using something other than `TDBGrid` (like a `TStringGrid`) and implement your own internal storage. However, `TClientDataSet` doesn't have to be a disk file, if the amount of data you're retrieving is manageable in memory; all of the data can just stay there without being a "local copy" (an "in-memory dataset").

Answer (score 0):

To use a grid you need these components ...
SQLQuery
DataSetProvider
ClientDataSet
DataSource
DBGrid